# Cpp files don't get build by Eclipse with llvm toolchain

Tags: eclipse, llvm, eclipse-cdt

I have simple project in eclipse consisting of two files [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQrLd.png)

But when i build it says 'nothing to build'. When i rename those files to *.c and *.h it builds. So how to make it build cpp and hpp files?

Eclipse version oxygen 4.7.2, llvm 6.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was in the "nature" of the project. I accidentally created c-project instead of c++. It was not obvious to find that out from project settings